# Play layer 2 then go back to layer 1 frame 1 with only main code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

How do i play layer 2and when finished go back to layer 1 frame 1 only in the main based code and no frame code?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily put gotoAndPlay(1) on a keyframe to go back to the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

Flash doesn't let you manage layers, you're going to need to make what ever is in the layers separately accessible by the code and manage them in the Document class.

You're also probably going to have to add some more details about what you're trying to do.